# Unix searches declared functions before the PATH

Tags: command-line, path, which

`Unix` searches first among the declared functions before the `PATH`:

```
$ order() { echo "hello from function"; }
$ order
hello from function

$ which order
/usr/bin/which: no order in (all:the:paths)

$ vim order
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello from somewhere"
:wq

$ chmod +x order
$ export PATH=~/:$PATH

$ hash -r

$ which order
~/order

$ order
hello from function
```

Is there a way to tell `unix` to search in the `PATH` before the declared functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"unix" doesn't interpret commands – shell programs do. So this depends on which shell you use.

In sh/bash/zsh, you can use use the `command` built-in:

```
$ order
hello from function

$ command order
hello from somewhere

$
```

There is no global setting for this.